# catkin_make is not working!

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin_make suddenly stopped working. When I am trying I am only getting the below output. Please kindly help. I am using Indigo

```
Base path: /home/saikishor/catkin_ws

Source space: /home/saikishor/catkin_ws/src

Build space: /home/saikishor/catkin_ws/build

Devel space: /home/saikishor/catkin_ws/devel

Install space: /home/saikishor/catkin_ws/install

WARNING: Package name "soar-to-ros_interface" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits and underscores.
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/saikishor/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/saikishor/catkin_ws/build"
####
[ 50%] Built target ros_project_gencfg

[100%] Built target ros_project
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256677/catkin_make-is-not-working!!!/) by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 228 on 2017-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-10**:
I don't see any error messages in the output. Can you explain what you expect it to be doing, and how it isn't working?

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2017-03-10**:
Yes I also don't see any error, but I want to compile a package with catkin_make The result is nothing, it is not able to create the new nodes!!!!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-10**:
It looks like it built a node called `ros_project`. You may want to check that there's a package.xml in each package, and it would help if you post your CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2017-03-11**:
Actually, I have created a new package called package_pub_sub, but there is no info about that package and the nodes are not created for that package....

Please find the CMakeLists and Package.xml here:

CMakeLists : http://pastebin.com/X5E5apWM

Package.xml : http://pastebin.com/QHUTAm9G

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-11**:
It looks like your package.xml may not be named properly; it should be all lowercase: `package.xml` (if catkin_make can't detect your package.xml, it won't build your package)

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2017-03-11**:
Yes sir, it was all in lowercase "package.xml", but still this happens. I don't know the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to change your package name: soar-to-ros_interface to soar_to_ros_interface, remove hyphens and see what happens. This is the only warning given out during compilation.

---

Originally posted by [Daksh Shukla](https://answers.ros.org/users/24949/daksh-shukla/) with karma: 26 on 2017-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1